# Android - mongodb RESTful integration

Tags: android, mongodb, rest

I'm developing an app which needs to occasionally export a document (csv or txt) to a server. I'm not certain what would be the best practice in this case? I read quite a lot about RESTful web services, but not sure if they'd work in case of files rather than simple id related queries.

Android app does not need to retrieve anything from mongo, it just need to send text to the server which then parses it and stores in mongo. How should I approach implementing that?

Many thanks!

Comment: on the client look at Http(s)UrlConnection or at Http clients ( 3 party like OkHttp ) On client , get csv or txt to body of your POST or in suitable instance for the 'body' in httpUrlConn object  ( outputStream's bytes ).   POST it .. On server just implement your REST service on a path that will be used by the client

Comment: @RobertRowntree, some code snippet would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem using Spring framework on the server side (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and following class on client (android):

```
public class RestClient {

public RestClient() {
}

public void export(JSONArray data) {
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("dataArray", data.toString());
    exportToWebService(params);
}

public void exportToWebService(RequestParams params){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = "CHANGE URL HERE";

    client.get(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            // Validation + error handling goes here
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                              String content) {

            // When Http response code is '404'
            if (statusCode == 404) {
                Log.d("WS Response", "404 response");
            }
            // When Http response code is '500'
            else if (statusCode == 500) {
                Log.d("WS Response", "500 response");
            }
            // When Http response code other than 404, 500
            else {
                Log.d("WS Response", "statusCode: " + statusCode);
                Log.d("WS Response", "Throwable error: " + error.toString());
                Log.d("WS Response", "content: " + content);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}